# For yaml load use open vs with

Tags: python

I have a program that reads yaml configs, just read only. I am wondering which one of the following is more Pythonic

```
try:
    config = yaml.load(open(filepath))
except Exception as error:
    print error
```

vs using a with statement

```
try:
    with open(filepath) as f:
        config = yaml.load(f)
except Exception as error:
    print error
```

I prefer the first one cause its simpler to read and since there are no write I don't think there will be issues with file closing gracefully. Thoughts?

Comment: second one seems better

Comment: The first one leaks a file descriptor.

Comment: dont forget close the file once dont need it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use the second. From the documentation:

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.